# How do I go from a bash script that calls a python script to a python script calling a bash script?

Tags: python, bash

I currently have the following piece of code in bash, now I want to do this in python as well. However the python script being called is very long and changing that to a function would be a very tedious task. How can I do this in python without modifying the script being called?

```
gfs15_to_am10.py $LAT $LON $ALT $GFS_CYCLE $FORECAST_HOUR \
        > layers.amc 2>layers.err
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use os lib.

```
import os
os.system("bash commands")
```

Two option to use parameters:

option A:

```
import os
LAT = ''
os.system(f"echo {LAT}")
```

option B:

use argparse lib to get parameters as script arguments:
[argparse python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html)